# mysql use fields value while insert a record

Tags: mysql

A simple question!:

Can I use my field value in an insert query?

For example, I've a field named `id`, it is an `auto_increment` field. i want to add this field value to another field. while I'm inserting it.

A simple php code of my need:

```
$query_1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('abcd')"); // id automatically increment
$query_2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'abcd'"); // selects previous id
// fetches result //
$query_3 = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET code = '" . $id + 1000 . "' WHERE id = '" . $id . "');
```

Can you convert it to just 1 query?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in one query but you can do it in 2 for sure:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES ('abcd')"); 
$id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET code = '" . $id + 1000 . "' WHERE id = '" . $id . "');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it with one query:

```
$query_1 = "INSERT INTO table (note) VALUES ('abcd'); UPDATE table SET code = LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1000 where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```

I can't remember if mysql allows multiple queries in one command - I think maybe not, so try this:

```
$query_1 = "INSERT INTO table (note) VALUES ('abcd')";
$query_2 = "UPDATE table SET code = id + 1000 where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```